# Get posts with any value in attribute

Tags: wp-query, woocommerce-offtopic, get-posts

Hello I am trying to do this query that extract woocommerce products with 3 attributes (Collezione, Finitura, Pietre). But we can have none,1,2 or 3 filters set, so I wanna ask you which value I have to set if the filter is not set. I thought -1 but this is not working here.

Here below you can find my code. Thanks in advance.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'tax_query'             => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'taxonomy'      => 'product_cat',
            'field' => 'term_id',
            'terms'         => $cat_id,
            'operator'      => 'IN' 
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy'      => 'pa_collezione',
            'field' => 'term_taxonomy_id', 
            'terms'         => $pa_collezione,
            'operator'      => 'IN' 
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy'      => 'pa_finitura',
            'field' => 'term_taxonomy_id',
            'terms'         => $pa_finitura,
            'operator'      => 'IN'
        ),            
        array(
            'taxonomy'      => 'pa_pietre',
            'field' => 'term_taxonomy_id',
            'terms'         => $pa_pietre,
            'operator'      => 'IN'
        )
    )
);

$products = get_posts( $args );
```

Comment: So do you want posts with **any** of those?

Comment: Yes but I found a solution setting 'NOT IN' when the value is -1. Thank you for your time.

Comment:  that's a horrifyingly slow/expensive query to make, avoid `NOT` queries at all costs

Comment: What u can suggest to me ?

Comment: Tag them with a common tag indicating that they're to be shown, or change the `relation` to `OR`?